# Refactoring curent javascript?

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have some script thats creates a  activ css on link, but ihave i problem that i think there is a lot f IF statments, can someone help me to refactor that code?

```
    var link = window.location.pathname;
    var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

    var hl = $('#ih').val();



    if (hl == 'True') {
        var currentPageName = 'WVD';
    }

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("R") > -1) {
        var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
    }

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("C") > -1) {
        var currentPageName = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
    }

    if (location.pathname == "/") {
        var currentPageName = 'MD';
    }

    $(".main-navigation ul li a").each(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        if (link.indexOf(currentPageName) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).css("color", "white");
            $(this).css("text-decoration", "bold");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can remove 2 if `window.location.href.indexOf("R") > -1` and `window.location.href.indexOf("C") > -1`

Comment: If at all possible, you would be doing this on the server-side that generates the code in the first place or in the raw HTML where you can add an `active` class or whatever.

Comment: declare the variable currentPageName only outside the if statement, otherwise in each function does not exist any change